# Помогите с регулярным выражением на проверку имени

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка которая проверят чтобы введены были только буквы, но не цифры. Но она пропускает выражения вида: чьёТоИмя12331. Не пускает если только цифры вводить

```
name.matches("^[0-9]+")
```

Comment: Нужны только английские буквы? Нужны ещё и русские? Что делать с тире ("Петров-Водкин")?

Answer (score 0):

```
^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z][а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: зачем дважды повторять? :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getReg(){

const input = document.querySelector('[type = "text"]');
let bool;

const h = document.querySelector('h3');

if (input.value.match(/\D/g).length == input.value.length)
bool = true;
else bool = false;
h.innerHTML += bool + "  ";
}
```

```html
<input type = "text">
<input type = "submit" onclick = getReg()>
<h3> </h3>
```